# Grabbing data from New York Times API

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the NY Times API (developer.nytimes.com/docs) to do the following:

```
var nytimes_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/28/us/in-western-washington-state-mudslides-pose-hint-of-danger.html';
// code taking nytimes_url
// and retrieving the headline, the byline, and the date of the article
```

So far I've tried using the [Symantic API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/semantic_api), specifically [this request](http://prototype.nytimes.com/gst/apitool/index.html?api_id=15&request_id=2&article_uri=2010%2F10%2F06%2Fbusiness%2Fmedia%2F06tribune&fields=article_list&offset=&resp_format=json&perform_request=Make+Request&use_pp=on), but the problem is that [the article](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/06/business/media/06tribune.html?pagewanted=all)'s title is `At Flagging Tribune, Tales of a Bankrupt Culture` and that String shows up inconsistently in the JSON text that's returned. I'm wondering if anyone can help me make this more efficient.

Comment: I guess it's an issue on the NYT side, not yours

Comment: I see, Topener, but do you have any suggestions? It'd be pretty cumbersome to search through that JSON to find the entry I want.

Comment: Can you show the inconsistently of json string?

Comment: What about using Article Search API and set Search Query to: `title:"At Flagging Tribune, Tales of a Bankrupt Culture"`?

Comment: @ PrimosK The problem with the Article Search API is that I do not know the article title in the first place. All I know is the inputted URL, so somehow I need to use that url to then find the headline, etc.

Comment: @ OammieR The data for the article of interest is located in random parts of the API. For example, using `ctrl-f` to find `At Flagging Tribune, Tales of a Bankrupt Culture` reveals it in different locations. How can I be sure where exactly to search so that I can get the headline, byline, etc?

Comment: Okay, I think I might be able to make this work. By looping through the JSON text and finding the url I inputted, and using that index to find the other info I need. I have one problem though. I can't seem to be able to get the JSON successfully. Can someone help with this? See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/).

Comment: I also tried using the YQL. [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/1/) but it's messy. Can someone help with parsing that?

Comment: Oops [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3NdEY/3/) is a better link.